# Getting the following error: "EnvironmentError: Unable to find libfuse"

Tags: python, load-testing, mqtt

I'm trying to load test my MQTT network on a CentOS7 machine by using [this repositorie](https://github.com/remakeelectric/mqtt-malaria/issues/22) on github. I executed the following commands to install the python-mosquitto dependency.

```
# yum install python-pip
# pip install mosquitto
```

Then I built and installed the setup.py file located in the repository file:

```
# python setup.py build
# python setup.py install
```

When trying to use the package, an error was thrown:

```
# malaria publish -P 2 -n 100 -H localhost -s 10
```

Error:

```
# malaria publish -P 2 -n 100 -H localhost -s 10malaria publish -P 2 -n 100 -H localhost -s 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/malaria", line 5, in <module>
pkg_resources.run_script('mqtt-malaria==0.1-77-g7ae4c97', 'malaria')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 540, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1455, in run_script
    execfile(script_filename, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mqtt_malaria-0.1_77_g7ae4c97-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/malaria", line 30, in <module>
import beem.main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mqtt_malaria-0.1_77_g7ae4c97-py2.7.egg/beem/main.py", line 34, in <module>
import beem.cmds
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mqtt_malaria-0.1_77_g7ae4c97-py2.7.egg/beem/cmds/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
import beem.cmds.subscribe
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mqtt_malaria-0.1_77_g7ae4c97-py2.7.egg/beem/cmds/subscribe.py", line 34, in <module>
import beem.listen
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mqtt_malaria-0.1_77_g7ae4c97-py2.7.egg/beem/listen.py", line 40, in <module>
import fuse
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/fuse.py", line 69, in <module>
EnvironmentError: Unable to find libfuse
```

Googling the error didn't provide me any answers. Did I do something wrong in the install process? I don't have much experience with the usage/building of cloned Github Repositories.

Comment: Do you have libfuse installed?

Comment: Note that libfuse is a system (C, I guess) package you need to install via your package manager, not a Python dependency you're missing.

Comment: Yes, libfuse was already installed. @Two-Bit Alchemist because you mentioned to install libfuse via package manager, I removed the installed libfuse it and reinstalled it with [this rpm](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/29071298/dir/centos_7/com/fuse-libs-2.9.2-5.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) and now it works. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If running CentOS you may want to do "yum install fuse-python", which will install fuse-libs as dependencies. It worked for me after doing that.

Comment: Improve your answer OR This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you earn sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. If you have a related but different question, ask a new question referencing this one if it will help provide context.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13343996)

Comment: @MortenJensen Looks okay to me.

Comment: This was a helpful answer to me--specifically, even when installing fusepy from pip, you'll need to yum install fuse-libs, which is different than the error message which says it's missing libfuse.

Answer (score 0):

The issues page on the repository (the issue right before the one you linked to) mentions exactly this problem.

The solution, as you've found is to install fusepy separately, either from your package manager or with `pip install fusepy`.